# Register types based on base class

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm trying to figure out Windsor as an IOC container.
The problem I'm facing right now is to register all of my viewmodels at once.

I've taken a look at the docs and thought that the following code should work.
However, when I check the container afterwards, nothing is registered.

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                          .BasedOn<ViewModelBase>()
                          .LifestyleTransient());
```

where `ViewModelBase` is my baseclass.

Also tried the following:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
         .InSameNamespaceAs<MainWindowViewModel>()
         .LifestyleTransient());
```

The necessary dependencies can be resolved, the viewmodels not.
I suppose I'm missing something obvious here?

**Edit**

My dependencies are registered as follows:

```
this.container.Register(Component.For<IDALHandler>().ImplementedBy<DALHandler>());
this.container.Register(Component.For<IBLHandler>().ImplementedBy<BLHandler>());
```

***UPDATE***

Since the suggestions didn't work, I was planning on adding the code from my baseclass and viewmodel here.
While doing so I noticed that my viewmodel-class was `internal sealed`. When changing it to `public sealed`, the above code did work.

Can someone explain why internal classes can't be registered in the container?
I've already tested other IOC containers with the exact same setup and they didn't complain about it.

Comment: How are you referring to to your viewmodel as dependency? According to your registration you should refer to the viewModel as concrete implementation, not as an interface.

Comment: Not sure about this but I thought that `.BasedOn<ViewModelBase>`would register all viewmodels since they inherrit from the abstract baseclass. The goal is to register all viewmodels at once so I don't need to add a new "register"-line each time a viewmodel is added to the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example of registration started working well in my application when I added [selection of the service for component](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Selecting_service_for_the_component_15). E.g. **`.WithService.AllInterfaces()`**

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn(typeof(MyBaseClass<>))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
);

container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
    .InSameNamespaceAs<MyBaseClass>()
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
);
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to register internal types, **`.IncludeNonPublicTypes()`** should be used.

```
public class ExampleTest
{
    [Test]
    public void MyBaseClass_Base()
    {
        var target = new WindsorContainer();

        target.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
            .BasedOn(typeof(MyBaseClass<>))
            .WithService.Base()
            //.LifestylePerWebRequest()
        );

        //assert
        target.Resolve<MyBaseClass<int>>().Should().BeOfType<A>();
        target.Resolve<MyBaseClass<string>>().Should().BeOfType<B>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyBaseClass_Self()
    {
        var target = new WindsorContainer();

        target.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
            .BasedOn(typeof(MyBaseClass<>))
            .WithService.Self()
            //.LifestylePerWebRequest()
        );

        //assert
        target.Resolve<MyBaseClass<int>>().Should().BeOfType<MyBaseClass<int>>();
        target.Resolve<MyBaseClass<string>>().Should().BeOfType<MyBaseClass<string>>();
        target.Resolve<A>().Should().BeOfType<A>();
        target.Resolve<B>().Should().BeOfType<B>();
    }
}

internal class MyBaseClass<T>
{
}

internal class A : MyBaseClass<int>
{
}

internal class B : MyBaseClass<string>
{
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. See the update of my question. Turns out that Windsor doesn't like internal classes.

Comment: In order to register internal types, **`.IncludeNonPublicTypes()`** should be used.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your viewmodels have been registered in the container, but they are not resolvable through their interface.

Set a breakpoint after the registration and check if container has been filled as expected.

**UPDATE** as per my comment below:
Keep in mind "group" registration (Classes.) skips internal class.

If they have been registered, let say you have a ViewModel like this

```
public class MyViewModel1 : ViewModelBase, IMyViewModel1


container.Resolve<MyViewModel1>() // resolve

container.Resolve<IMyViewModel1>() // no resolve
```

to accomplish the second resolving scenario you have to do what Ilya pointed about about adding WithService during registration, so you can resolve by interface instead of by concrete.

Comment: This didn't work. See the update of my question. Turns out that Windsor doesn't like internal classes.

Comment: You can register internal class, but only explicitly/one by one(Component.For...), "group" registration (Classes.) skips internal class

Comment: Thanks. Thought so, did already test a one by one registration for the viewmodels. If you update your answer, I will accept it.