# Resolving generic constructor arguments in Castle with inheritance & no interfaces

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

Though I've used generics in Castle Windsor before, this particular combination has currently got me stumped.

I'd like to resolve it as a constructor argument, which is simulated in this unit test by explicitly calling resolve().

But I cannot figure out what combination of registration and resolving I need to do.
I show the code with a failing test, below, to make the problem clear.

```
    public abstract class BaseSettings<T> where T : class
    {
        protected void Save(T obj)
        { }
    }

    public class AddinSettings : BaseSettings<AddinSettings>
    { }

    public class OtherSettings : BaseSettings<OtherSettings>
    { }

    public class LogConfig<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly BaseSettings<T> _client;

        public LogConfig(BaseSettings<T> client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public BaseSettings<T> Client
        {
            get { return _client; }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void resolve_generics()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<OtherSettings >());
        var otherSettings = container.Resolve<LogConfig<OtherSettings>>();
        Assert.That(otherSettings, Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is needed to register an open generic type `LogConfig<>` as @Marwijn did.

Then, **you can register all `BaseSettings<T>` implementations by means of selecting [base type/condition](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Selecting_base_typecondition_3) and [service for the component](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Selecting_service_for_the_component_15) using `BasedOn(typeof(BaseSettings<>))` and `WithService.Base()`.**

The following test method proves it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void resolve_generics()
{
    // arrange
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        Component.For(typeof(LogConfig<>)),
        Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof(BaseSettings<>)).WithService.Base());

    //act
    var otherSettings = container.Resolve<LogConfig<OtherSettings>>();
    var addinSettings = container.Resolve<LogConfig<AddinSettings>>();

    // assert
    otherSettings.Should().NotBeNull();
    otherSettings.Client.Should().BeOfType<OtherSettings>();

    addinSettings.Should().NotBeNull();
    addinSettings.Client.Should().BeOfType<AddinSettings>();
}
```

There is another answer on the similar question about [registering types based on base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349269/register-types-based-on-base-class/20356804#20356804).

Comment: Good improvement. Thanks I didn't know that based on works with open generics.

Comment: Fantastic yes, that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(LogConfig<>)),
    Component.For<BaseSettings<OtherSettings>>().ImplementedBy<OtherSettings>());
```

Goodluck,
Marwijn.