# Using dynamically created generic interface's methods in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IGeneric<T>
{
    Method1(T t);
    Method2(T t);
}
```

Using following piece of code, I create an instance of `IGeneric<T>` based on an entity type, dynamically:

```
var entityType  = entity.GetType();
var genericType = typeof(IGeneric<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
var result      = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

For example if my entity is an `Order` the result will be `IGeneric<Order>`.
Now, how can I call the result's methods, for example I want to call `Method1()`:

```
result.Method1();
```

But the `Method1()` isn't accessible.

Comment: The members of the interface in your sample don't have any relation to the generic type argument `T`. Is this also the case for the real problem? If so, the easiest approach would be to move the members to a non-generic interface, derive `IGeneric<T>` from the new interface and cast the return of `Activator.CreateInstance` to this base interface.

Comment: @Markus: yeah, i is a case of real problem, I have an IRepository<T> that has Insert(T entity), update(T entity) ,...

Answer (score 1):

The following sample shows how to call methods that are located in a generic interface:

```
using System;

public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T Method1(T input);
}

public class MyImpl : IMyInterface<int>
{
    public int Method1(int input)
    {
        return input * 2;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Concrete type that implements the interface
        Type implType = typeof(MyImpl);
        // Type of generic interface
        Type genType = typeof(IMyInterface<>);
        // Interface for int
        Type concType = genType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
        // Create instance
        object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(implType);
        // Retrieve member that you want to call
        var member = concType.GetMethod("Method1");
        // Invoke member on instance
        var result = member.Invoke(inst, new object[] { 123 });
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", 123, result);
    }
}
```

You can run and edit the sample [here](http://ideone.com/KOl0Px).

Comment: Thanks, you used concrete type that implement the interface in your code, Is it possible that I do not use it? because I want delegate concrete type creation to my IoC container and only use the interfaces in my code.

Comment: @Masoud: this should be no difference; just replace `Type implType = typeof(MyImpl);` with `Type implType = entity.GetType()` as you did in your sample. It does not matter how you acquire the type.

Comment: You used `Type implType = typeof(MyImpl);` to get the `IMyInterface<int>` concrete type, but if I use `Type implType = entity.GetType()` the result will be `Order` and this does not have desired result.

Comment: @Masoud: I think you have to change the type parameter in the line `Type concType = genType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));` to `Type concType = genType.MakeGenericType(entityType);`. However, in your sample, you try to create an instance of the interface (`Activator.CreateInstance(genericType)`); this will not work. You need to create an instance of the type that implements the interface.

Comment: But in run time I get "Cannot create an instance of an interface." error, when program want to run the `Activator.CreateInstance(genericType)`.

Comment: @Masoud: you can't create an instance of an interface. You need to create an instance of a type that implements the interface. How you get to this type depends on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

**I think that any [IoC container](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx), framework that knows how to resolve types, is something that you are looking for.** First [open generic types can be registered, then their inmplementations can be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349269/register-types-based-on-base-class/20356804#20356804).

According to your code block I suggest you use the following approach. It uses `Activator` to create an instance of `Repository<T>` that inherits `IRepository<T>`. `IRepository` interface provides an ability to cast `result` to the non-generic type an invoke `Insert` method without reflection.:

```
public class GenericInterfaceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void IncertsStringEntity()
    {
        // Arrange.
        var entity = "100500";

        var entityType = entity.GetType();
        var genericType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

        // Act.
        (result as IRepository).Insert(entity);

        // Assert.
        result.Should().BeOfType<Repository<string>>();
        var repository = result as Repository<string>; 

        repository.DataSource.Should().Contain(entity);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void InsertsIntegerEntity()
    {
        // Arrange.
        var entity = 100500;

        var entityType = entity.GetType();
        var genericType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

        // Act.
        (result as IRepository).Insert(entity);

        // Assert.
        result.Should().BeOfType<Repository<int>>();
        var repository = result as Repository<int>; 

        repository.DataSource.Should().Contain(entity);
    }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
}

public interface IRepository
{
    void Insert(object entity);
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, IRepository
{
    public List<TEntity> DataSource { get; set; }

    public Repository()
    {
        DataSource = new List<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        DataSource.Add(entity);
    }

    void IRepository.Insert(object entity)
    {
        Insert((TEntity)entity);
    }
}
```