# Castle Windsor registering components that match the same services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have the following code in my MVC application which works fine.

```
container.Register(Component.For<CountryServiceBase>()
    .ImplementedBy<CountryService>()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Castle Windsor creates a component

```
CountryService / CountryServiceBase
```

My controller gets an instantiated object here :

```
public class MyController : MainController
{
    public CountryServiceBase CountryService {get; set;} // instantiate by Ioc : OK
```

My problem is that I have a lot of classes to register. So using Castle Windsor I did the following :

```
container.Register(
    Types
    .FromAssemblyNamed("mynamespace")
    .BasedOn(typeof(ServiceBase<>))
    .WithService.Base()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Castle Windsor creates my components

```
CountryService / ServiceBase<Country>
CountryServiceBase / ServiceBase<Country>
```

But my MVC Application awaits a CountryService / CountryServiceBase and I don't know how to specify to Castle Windsor that it can match back CountryServiceBase to CountryService as both those classes (one of them being an abstract one) inherits ServiceBase

Is it even possible ?

*Note : I posted a similar question but my investigation leads to a more accurate one so I deleted the old one.*

Comment: Try to change `public CountryServiceBase CountryService {get; set;}` by `public ServiceBase<Country> CountryService {get; set;}`

Comment: It would work but in abstract class CountryServiceBase, I have several declared methods. Otherwise it would work.

Comment: Maybe `BasedOn(typeof(CountryServiceBase))`?

Comment: Doing so I would have to manually register all my classes and my goal is to avoid such a thing. Thanks anyway

Comment: `WithService.AllInterfaces()`?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt : I tried but It doesnt work either. WithAllInterfaces() just find that I have an IService<T> but the problem remains. My controllers needs the CountryServiceBase to be instantiated with a CountryService object. CountryService inherits CountryServiceBase, and CountryServiceBase Inheriste ServiceBase<Country>.

Comment: @AMS, `WithAllInterfaces` works for interfaces only. Could you provide class diagramme that you have right now. There might be no problem with  `Windsor` api but with inheritance that you have in your application.

Comment: Try using `Classes` instead of `Types`, as shown here: [Register types based on base class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20356804). Combined with `BasedOn()` and `InSameNamespaceAs<>()` it should be possible to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Usually [services](https://github.com/ilyapalkin/Windsor/blob/master/docs/services-and-components.md#service) are interfaces. That's why [`AllInterfaces()`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/397b951fb8717b408ebacd941ac7d51e1e1ff113/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#allinterfaces) works for others.

If you check API you'll find [`Select()`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/397b951fb8717b408ebacd941ac7d51e1e1ff113/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#select) method that can be used easily.

> If none of the above options suits you you can provide your own
>   selection logic as a delegate and pass it to `WithService.Select()`
>   method.

So registration code could be the following:

```
    container.Register(Types.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn(typeof(ServiceBase<>))
        .WithService.AllInterfaces()
        .WithService.Select((t, b) => t.BaseType != null
                ? new[] { t.BaseType }
                : new Type[0])
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

This solution is quite quick-and-dirty but at least it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your `CountryServiceBase` class is abstract, using `Classes` instead of `Types` should help to avoid having the base class registered (see [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#selecting-assembly)):

> Classes  on the other hand pre-filters the types to only consider non-abstract classes

However it does not look like you can avoid mentioning `CountryServiceBase` in your registration, maybe using `OrBasedOn(CountryServiceBase)` then your implementation will be available as both `ServiceBase<>` and `CountryServiceBase`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get all classes inheriting from your serviceBase.
You can find a the way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class)

Then you can implement the code above to instantiate all the services.

Comment: This could be an idea. I'll wait for the bounty to finish but I like this solution as I could add services without having to register them one by one as I create them on my project.